# Mongo 2.6.9 process stopping, no error logs

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo 2.6.9 process running on a Linux SMP instance.  Here's `uname -a` with the server name redacted:

```
Linux xxx.xxxx.com 3.13.0-042stab085.20 #1 SMP Sun Jul 20 13:27:24 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

A couple of times in the past, the Mongo instance has crashed, but it has been infrequent (every other month), and I have not investigated.  Today it's happened 5 times.  Of course I looked at log files first.  Nothing jumps out at me as alarming.  Here's the tail of the log file, right before a crash:

```
2015-05-27T18:29:12.547-0400 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:27 virt:691
2015-05-27T18:29:12.547-0400 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):480
2015-05-27T18:29:12.547-0400 [clientcursormon]  connections:10
2015-05-27T18:30:12.435-0400 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 0ms  for 6 files
```

I then edited `/etc/mongod.conf`, and changed `verbose` to `true`.  Now, in addition to the above, I just get some normal-looking `TTLMonitor` lines:

```
2015-05-27T18:33:12.435-0400 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 0ms  for 6 files
2015-05-27T18:33:12.495-0400 [TTLMonitor] query admin.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:3 nscannedObjects:3 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:315 nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
2015-05-27T18:33:12.496-0400 [TTLMonitor] query dtnajobs.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:5 nscannedObjects:5 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:51 nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
2015-05-27T18:33:12.496-0400 [TTLMonitor] query local.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:74 nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
```

I found on the MongoDB documentation page that I should try this for such crashes:

```
sudo grep mongod /var/log/messages
sudo grep score /var/log/messages
```

Neither of these files exist on this machine, so instead I grepped *all* log files, and came up with nothing relevant.

When I run the `mongo` command-line client, I do get this warning:

```
2015-05-27T18:36:24.216-0400 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.
```

Is it possible that this is something I should

I really need a way to identify what the problem is and fix it.  Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Perhaps already checked but , did you check the syslog looking for any out of memory kills?

Comment: I believe I did when this problem first manifested, but I will check again...maybe I missed it.

Comment: You don't provide enough informations to replicate or try to diagnose the problem. Which linux flavour are you using (yes, the kernel version isn't enough)? How and from where did you install mongo? What's your complete mongo configuration file? What's mongo's files size? 4 lines of logs aren't enough, you should post more. Also don't use the verbose option, enable higher level logging from inside mongo with the appropriate [parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/)